# What's the biggest bounty someone has been awarded for an answer?

Tags: discussion

I'm just really curious to know if there is any way to check for the largest bounty ever awarded to someone for an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Asked and answered over on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269743/which-answer-has-earned-highest-bounty-in-se-network). Although Ixrec is correct that Kyle Hale's legendary ID answer is the top-earner network-wide, I'm going to shamelessly steal from [rene's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269757/276025) with a network-wide [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/396019/which-answer-has-earned-highest-bounty-in-se-network):

[image]

Because SEDE is updated weekly, that query will sometimes not be perfectly accurate; nevertheless, it seems unlikely that anyone is going to beat Kyle's record anytime soon.

Comment: That Parenting question actually has two separate 1000 rep bounties

Comment: @CreationEdge You're right; that's an interesting bug

Answer (score 4):

If you mean total bounty rep on one post, regardless of how many people contributed bounties to the total, I believe [the accepted answer to "Story where the number 3 is the monster?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/story-where-the-number-3-is-the-monster/105743#105743) has the most bounty points of any post in the entire SE network: +3000

Comment: Currently +3,150!